# Chat application index array out of bounds error

Tags: c#

I am getting an index out of bounds error at this line of code:

```
 ---------------------------vvvvv-------------------------------------------
 >>> char character = Convert.ToChar(temp[1].Substring(0, 1).ToLower()); <<<
 ---------------------------^^^^^-------------------------------------------
```

(Whole code block)

```
 List<string> entries = new List<string>();
 List<string> pre_entries = new List<string>((string[])Regex.Split(data.Substring(3, data.Length - 3), ",,"));
 foreach (string message in pre_entries)
 {
    string[] temp = message.Split(new string[] { "~~||~~" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (temp.Length == 2)
    {
       char character = Convert.ToChar(temp[1].Substring(0, 1).ToLower());
       if (character == 'a' || character == 'b' || character == 'c' || character == 'd' || character == 'e' ||
           character == 'f' || character == 'g' || character == 'h' || character == 'i' || character == 'j' ||
           character == 'k' || character == 'l' || character == 'm' || character == 'n' || character == 'o' ||
           character == 'p' || character == 'q' || character == 'r' || character == 's' || character == 't' ||
           character == 'u' || character == 'v' || character == 'w' || character == 'x' || character == 'y' ||
           character == 'z')
    {
        entries.Add(ReplaceFirst(temp[1].Substring(13), ",", ": "));      
    }
    else if (temp.Length > 2)
    {
  290: char character = Convert.ToChar(temp[1].Substring(0, 1).ToLower());
       if (character == 'a' || character == 'b' || character == 'c' || character == 'd' || character == 'e' ||
           character == 'f' || character == 'g' || character == 'h' || character == 'i' || character == 'j' ||
           character == 'k' || character == 'l' || character == 'm' || character == 'n' || character == 'o' ||
           character == 'p' || character == 'q' || character == 'r' || character == 's' || character == 't' ||
           character == 'u' || character == 'v' || character == 'w' || character == 'x' || character == 'y' ||
           character == 'z')
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length / 2; i++)
          {
              entries.Add(ReplaceFirst(temp[i + 1], ",", ": "));
          }
       }
       else
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length / 2; i++)
           {
                entries.Add(ReplaceFirst(temp[i + 1].Substring(13), ",", ": "));
           }
       }
    }
    else { }
 }
```

Let's say the data we have going into this foreach loop is in the format of a `List<string>` and list has data like "554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User, blah 554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User2, stuff 545675~~~||~~~~567875, User3". The first part of the data `1,54134567851~~~||~~~` is irrelevant because the character count before the delimiter is wrong for this example. I'm not sure what type of message sets off the catch but whenever I do get an error in the application (chat application) it shows this error.

Error: Exception

Source: SimpleMan

Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

StackTrace: at SimpleMan.Server.Message() in X:\Projects\Visual Studio Projects\c#\SimpleMan\SimpleMan\Program.cs:line 290

HResult: -2146233080

Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Example:

If I have a string in the pre_entries list at index 0 : "554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User, blah 554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User2, stuff 545675~~~||~~~~567875, User3"

the temp string array would have 4 entries starting at the first,

> (index 0): "554655
>
> (index 1): "~~~||~~~123454,2 User, blah 554655"
>
> (index 2): "~~~||~~~123454,2 User2, stuff 545675"
>
> (index 3): "~~~||~~~~567875, User3"

Sometimes one of the strings would look like this "12332354~~~||~~~546546, User, blah" in temp which is why I have the if / then statements looking for possible character non-matches in this kind of situation.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? It seems to me that temp is shorter that 2 characters which would lead to temp[1] to throw an out of bounds exception

Comment: Side note: instead of those massive orelse blocks, you can check if the ASCII code is between 2 numbers.

Comment: Side note: It seem a bit overkill to use multiple `==` for each letter instead of `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'` or even regular expression... But it will make code shorter and less acceptable in code-troll answers.

Comment: BTW: Some hints; `if (character==....) ==> if (character>='a' && character<='z')` , `temp[1].Substring(0, 1) ==> temp[1][0]`

Comment: Yeah I did that just because I'm still learning about Regular Expressions and this is the sure fire way to me right now to do check for letters or whatever else. Thanks :D

Comment: Why the `new string[]` inside the `Split()`.  `Split()` returns a `string[]`... maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: # string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"[stop]"};  @http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx  I'm just creating a new string array in the split method because the split method does not accept just stand alone strings from what I have seen.

Comment: @ L.B: Do you recommend any good sources for learning how to properly use lambda expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `temp` doesn't have 2 entries.  Make sure that it does before you attempt to retrieve it.

**NOTE**: This may go without saying, but arrays are 0 indexed.  Meaning, if you want the first entry, do `[0]` and not `[1]`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant to add more delimiters of "~~~||~~~" because the data has multiple of them "554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User, blah 554655~~~||~~~123454,2 User2, stuff 545675~~~||~~~~567875, User3" – Update: I'm letting my application run currently with an updated else if replacing the first else statement in my source code. I also added an empty else block for basically catching (temp < 2). Come back in about two to three hours, thank you. 
 The else statement worked! Thank you so much for that as I didn't even think of that "temp doesn't have 2 entries". One step further!